Compilation error: no matching function for call to 'firebase::FirebaseClient::FirebaseClient(const char [44])'
This is my Arduino code for ESP8266.  I have used FirebaseClient library. I encounter errors after compiling. My goal is to take data from a device using esp and display on mobile app. Here I have tried to implement ESP8266 code using FirebaseClient library.
Code:
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <FirebaseClient.h>

// Wi-Fi credentials
const char* ssid = "< >";
const char* password = "<  >";

// Firebase configuration
 FirebaseClient client ("https://<  >.firebaseio.com"); // Replace with your Firestore URL

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    //connect to wifi
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    Serial.print("Connecting to Wifi");
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(500);
        Serial.print(".");
    }
    Serial.println("Connected to Wi-Fi");
 //   FirebaseClient client("https://<   >.firebaseio.com"); // Replace with your Firestore URL
    }

void writeData(float waterLevel) {
    String documentPath = "sensors/water_level"; // Firestore document path
    String jsonData = "{\"level\": " + String(waterLevel) + "}"; // JSON data format

    if (client.post(documentPath, jsonData)) {
        Serial.println("Data sent successfully");
    } else {
        Serial.println("Error sending data: " + client.error());
    }
}

void readData() {
    String documentPath = "sensors/water_level"; // Firestore document path
    if (client.get(documentPath)) {
        Serial.println("Data retrieved: " + client.responseBody());
    } else {
        Serial.println("Error reading data: " + client.error());
    }
}

void loop() {
    // Placeholder for sending and receiving data
    // Example of how to call the functions
    writeData(75.5); // Example water level
    delay(10000); // Wait for 10 seconds
    readData(); // Read the data
    delay(10000); // Wait for another 10 seconds
}

Error:
C:\Users\<  >\AppData\Local\Temp\.arduinoIDE-unsaved2024917-11596-xn4egq.2i22\sketch_oct17a\sketch_oct17a.ino:9:70: error: no matching function for call to 'firebase::FirebaseClient::FirebaseClient(const char [44])'
    9 |  FirebaseClient client ("https://<   >.firebaseio.com"); // Replace with your Firestore URL
      |                                                                      ^
In file included from C:\Users\<   >\AppData\Local\Temp\.arduinoIDE-unsaved2024917-11596-xn4egq.2i22\sketch_oct17a\sketch_oct17a.ino:2:
c:\Users\<  >\Documents\Arduino\libraries\FirebaseClient\src/FirebaseClient.h:128:9: note: candidate: 'firebase::FirebaseClient::FirebaseClient()'
  128 |         FirebaseClient() {}
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
c:\Users\<  >\Documents\Arduino\libraries\FirebaseClient\src/FirebaseClient.h:128:9: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
In file included from C:\Users\<  >\AppData\Local\Temp\.arduinoIDE-unsaved2024917-11596-xn4egq.2i22\sketch_oct17a\sketch_oct17a.ino:2:
c:\Users\<  >\Documents\Arduino\libraries\FirebaseClient\src/FirebaseClient.h:87:11: note: candidate: 'constexpr firebase::FirebaseClient::FirebaseClient(const firebase::FirebaseClient&)'
   87 |     class FirebaseClient : public AppBase
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
c:\Users\< >\Documents\Arduino\libraries\FirebaseClient\src/FirebaseClient.h:87:11: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const char [44]' to 'const firebase::FirebaseClient&'
C:\Users\< >\AppData\Local\Temp\.arduinoIDE-unsaved2024917-11596-xn4egq.2i22\sketch_oct17a\sketch_oct17a.ino: In function 'void writeData(float)':
C:\Users\< >\AppData\Local\Temp\.arduinoIDE-unsaved2024917-11596-xn4egq.2i22\sketch_oct17a\sketch_oct17a.ino:28:16: error: 'class firebase::FirebaseClient' has no member named 'post'
   28 |     if (client.post(documentPath, jsonData)) {
      |                ^~~~
C:\Users\<  >\AppData\Local\Temp\.arduinoIDE-unsaved2024917-11596-xn4egq.2i22\sketch_oct17a\sketch_oct17a.ino:31:56: error: 'class firebase::FirebaseClient' has no member named 'error'
   31 |         Serial.println("Error sending data: " + client.error());
      |                                                        ^~~~~
C:\Users\<  >\AppData\Local\Temp\.arduinoIDE-unsaved2024917-11596-xn4egq.2i22\sketch_oct17a\sketch_oct17a.ino: In function 'void readData()':
C:\Users\<  >\AppData\Local\Temp\.arduinoIDE-unsaved2024917-11596-xn4egq.2i22\sketch_oct17a\sketch_oct17a.ino:37:16: error: 'class firebase::FirebaseClient' has no member named 'get'
   37 |     if (client.get(documentPath)) {
      |                ^~~
C:\Users\<  >\AppData\Local\Temp\.arduinoIDE-unsaved2024917-11596-xn4egq.2i22\sketch_oct17a\sketch_oct17a.ino:38:52: error: 'class firebase::FirebaseClient' has no member named 'responseBody'
   38 |         Serial.println("Data retrieved: " + client.responseBody());
      |                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\<  >\AppData\Local\Temp\.arduinoIDE-unsaved2024917-11596-xn4egq.2i22\sketch_oct17a\sketch_oct17a.ino:40:56: error: 'class firebase::FirebaseClient' has no member named 'error'
   40 |         Serial.println("Error reading data: " + client.error());
      |                                                        ^~~~~

exit status 1

Compilation error: no matching function for call to 'firebase::FirebaseClient::FirebaseClient(const char [44])'

I have tried different forums. but couldn't find any lead.
